# Using one dynamic array for two struct objects in c++

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, dynamic

I tried running the code on a few compilers and got different results. I either got some weird exit code like `-1073741819 (0xC0000005)` or `free(): double free detected in tcache 2` or when debugging I got  `SIGTRAP (Trace/breakpoint trap) SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)`.

I'm 99% sure the problem is that I'm freeing the ships array twice. But why do I not get errors when I don't run func() twice on both players or if I change anything else in the code? **What is the problem exactly and how can I fix the error?**

**Yes** I am using a dynamic array instead of a vector, because I'm trying to practise and learn. **Yes** I know this memory allocation method creates memory fragmentation, but I never change the size of the matrix, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Code:

```
struct point_t {
  int x;
  int y;

  point_t();
};

point_t::point_t() {
  this->x = 0;
  this->y = 0;
}

struct ship_t {
  int size;
  point_t end_coords[2];
};

struct player_t {
  int **map;
  int map_size;
  ship_t *ships;
  int ships_count;

  player_t(int, ship_t *, int);
  ~player_t();
};

player_t::player_t(int map_size, ship_t *ships, int ships_count) {
  this->map = nullptr;
  this->map_size = map_size;
  this->ships = ships;
  this->ships_count = ships_count;
}

player_t::~player_t() {
  // Free map memory

  // Free each column (sub-array)
  for(int i = 0; i < map_size; i++) {
    delete[] map[i];
  }

  // Free each row (array of pointers)
  delete[] map;
  map = nullptr;
  map_size = 0;

  delete[] ships;
  ships = nullptr;
  ships_count = 0;
}

void func(player_t &player) {
  player.map = new int *[player.map_size];
  for(int i = 0; i < player.map_size; i++) {
    player.map[i] = new int[player.map_size];
    for(int j = 0; j < player.map_size; j++) {
      player.map[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
    ship_t *ships = new ship_t[(5 * 5) / 2];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ships[i].size = i + 1;
    }
    
    player_t player1 = player_t(5, ships, 5);
    player_t player2 = player_t(5, ships, 5);
    
    func(player1);
    func(player2);
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not be manually calling your destructors.  the compiler does that for you automatically.

Comment: When you're thinking "dynamic array", your next thought should *always* be `std::vector`.

Comment: You can't *initialize* in a function body, constructor or not. `this->end_coords[2] = {};` is an *assignment*. And you try to assign to the *third* element of your two-element array. As for `end_coords`, it doesn't need to be initialized, as that will be done by the default initialization of the array and the `point_t` constructor.

Comment: I recommend you invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn C++ "properly".

Comment: Not causing your current problem but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have another constructor which takes 3 arguments and if I remove my default constructor I get `error: no matching function for call to 'ship_t::ship_t()'`

Comment: *"Yes I am using a dynamic array instead of a vector, because I'm trying to practice and learn."*. Then implement your own `vector`, and use it.

Comment: @Jarod42 Why? I don't need the c++ vector's methods lik, push_back, pop_back, erase, insert, etc.

Comment: `std::vector` does much more than just that. The most important part is that you don't have to worry about memory allocations, or making your own copy/move constructors, or even your own destructors.

Comment: *Why? I don't need the c++ vector's methods lik, push_back, pop_back, erase, insert, etc* -- `int main() { ship_t s s; player_t p(1, &s, 1); player_t p2 = p; }` -- Try to fix the double-delete error you will get with this simple program.  Second, C++ programmers don't enumerate how many member functions a class has before they use it.  As long as the class provides the functionality desired, without bugs, is what is important.

Comment: Then another important thing is *time*.  If you had used `std::vector` from the start, you wouldn't have run into the issues you have now, and spend time posting a question on StackOverflow awaiting an answer.  You would have had more time to spend on programming the actual game instead of trying to micromanage "dynamic arrays".

Comment: *"I don't need the c++ vector's methods like push_back, pop_back, erase, insert, etc."*. So, don't implement them at start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your code with Visual Studio gives me:

```
HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#72) at 0x00B065E8.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.
```

when doing the `delete[] ships;`.

The first problem is that you are trying to initialize points in the ships constructor, but:

```
    this->end_coords[2] = {};
```

this statement is assigning a default initialized point to the **third** point in the `end_coords` member of ships. Unfortunately the array is two points large.

Moreover, since `player_t` destructor destroys ships, you are giving ownership of ships to `player_t`. But you are giving ownership of the same dynamic allocated array to two players:

```cpp
int main()
{
    ship_t *ships = new ship_t[(5 * 5) / 2];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ships[i].size = i + 1;
    }
    
    player_t player1 = player_t(5, ships, 5); // <-- ships
    player_t player2 = player_t(5, ships, 5); // <-- ships
```

Not a good idea. The same ships array is used by two players, which makes no sense, since each player should have his own ships, I guess.

Finally you shall not call the destructor of player, because it will be called again on return (scope exit).

## Minimal modifications fixed code:

Comment out this line in the `ship_t` constructor:

```
//this->end_coords[2] = {};
```

Allocate two ships arrays, to give each player ownership:

```
    ship_t *ships = new ship_t[(5 * 5) / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ships[i].size = i + 1;
    }
    player_t player1 = player_t(5, ships, 5);

    ship_t *ships2 = new ship_t[(5 * 5) / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ships2[i].size = i + 1;
    }
    player_t player2 = player_t(5, ships2, 5);
```

## A more C++ style solution

Let's call structs with their names. Then use default initialization within the struct to avoid useless constructors. Remove all allocations unless really really needed. Let's use `std::vector<>`.
I'm not a fan of vectors of vectors for maps, but in this case it is really a simple solution. No need to store the sizes when using vectors. Finally, copy the ship vector into each player, using move, in case there is some temporary being passed around.

```
#include <vector>

struct point {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
};

struct ship {
    int size = 0;
    point end_coords[2];
};

struct player {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> map;
    std::vector<ship> ships;

    player(int map_size, std::vector<ship> ships_) :
        map(map_size, std::vector<int>(map_size)),
        ships(std::move(ships_)) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<ship> ships;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        ships.push_back({ i + 1 });
    }

    player player1(5, ships);
    player player2(5, ships);

    return 0;
}
```

## A more C++ style version, with memory allocation:

Here I'm not using `std::vector` (but it's not a good idea). Notice how we can initialize a vector int to 0, and that you don't need a pointer to pointer. With a couple of operators it's much easier to manage the map. As an example I'm printing your map. Suggestion: don't use `i` and `j`. Use `r` and `c` for rows and columns, to avoid exchanging their meaning by accident.

```
#include <iostream>

struct point {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
};

struct ship {
    int size = 0;
    point end_coords[2];
};

// use _ after names, to make clear that these are members
struct player {
    int *map_;           // owned
    int map_size_;
    ship *ships_;        // owned
    int ships_count_;

    // player constructor copies the ships vector
    player(int map_size, const ship *ships, int ships_count) :
        map_size_{ map_size }, ships_count_{ ships_count }
    { 
        map_ = new int[map_size * map_size]{}; // notice the initializer here to default zero
        ships_ = new ship[ships_count];
    }

    // Rule of 4: if you own memory, you need all these 4 methods. Or delete them.
    player(const player&) = delete;
    player& operator=(const player&) = delete;

    ~player() {
        delete[] map_;  // no setting to nullptr: these will never be accessed anymore
        delete[] ships_;
    }

    int size() const { return map_size_; }
    int& operator()(int r, int c) {
        return map_[r * map_size_ + c];
    }
    const int& operator()(int r, int c) const {
        return map_[r * map_size_ + c];
    }
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const player& p) {
    auto size = p.size();
    for (int r = 0; r < size; ++r) {
        for (int c = 0; c < size; ++c) {
            if (p(r, c) == 0) {
                std::cout << "~";
            }
            else {
                std::cout << p(r, c);
            }
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    ship ships[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        ships[i].size = i + 1;
    }

    player player1(5, ships, 5);
    player player2(5, ships, 5);

    std::cout << "player1:\n" << player1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "player2:\n" << player2 << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```